# Sceneform for ARCore create box method

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I'm trying to create a simple red box in Sceneform for Android ARCore with the ShapeFactory. There isn't an example of this that I could find, the closest being changing materials on an existing object.
Below I think I have the code mostly right with an attempt for a node for the box being created and attached to an anchor node, with the actual box material, geometry and position also being created and attached as the renderable of the node.
The error shows that "boxo" is never used and that "boxo" is not recognised when attempted to be setRenderable()

```
package com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.hellosceneform;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.ar.core.Anchor;
import com.google.ar.core.HitResult;
import com.google.ar.core.Plane;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.math.Vector3;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Color;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.MaterialFactory;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ModelRenderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Renderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ShapeFactory;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.TransformableNode;

import static com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ShapeFactory.makeCube;

/**
 * This is an example activity that uses the Sceneform UX package to make common AR tasks easier.
 */
public class HelloSceneformActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private static final String TAG = HelloSceneformActivity.class.getSimpleName();
  private static final double MIN_OPENGL_VERSION = 3.0;

  private ArFragment arFragment;
  private ModelRenderable pipesRenderable;

  @Override
  @SuppressWarnings({"AndroidApiChecker", "FutureReturnValueIgnored"})
  // CompletableFuture requires api level 24
  // FutureReturnValueIgnored is not valid
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!checkIsSupportedDeviceOrFinish(this)) {
      return;
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ux);
    arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ux_fragment);

    // When you build a Renderable, Sceneform loads its resources in the background while returning
    // a CompletableFuture. Call thenAccept(), handle(), or check isDone() before calling get().
    ModelRenderable.builder()
        .setSource(this, Uri.parse("pipes.sfb"))
        .build()
        .thenAccept(renderable -> pipesRenderable = renderable)
        .exceptionally(
            throwable -> {
              Toast toast =
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load pipes renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
              toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
              toast.show();
              return null;
            });

    arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(
        (HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent) -> {
          if (pipesRenderable == null) {
            return;
          }

          // Create the Anchor.
          Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
          AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
          anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());

          // Create the transformable andy and add it to the anchor.
          TransformableNode pipes = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
          pipes.setParent(anchorNode);
          pipes.setRenderable(pipesRenderable);
          pipes.select();

          TransformableNode cube = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
          cube.setParent(anchorNode);
         // MaterialFactory
         // ModelRenderable box = ShapeFactory.makeCube(new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f), new Vector3(0.0f, 0.15f, 0.0f), boxMat);
            //
            MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(this, new Color(android.graphics.Color.RED))
                    .thenAccept(
                            material -> {
                               ModelRenderable boxo = ShapeFactory.makeCube(new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f), new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f), material); });
          cube.setRenderable(boxo);
          cube.select();

        });
  }

}

  */

  /**
   * Returns false and displays an error message if Sceneform can not run, true if Sceneform can run
   * on this device.
   *
   * <p>Sceneform requires Android N on the device as well as OpenGL 3.0 capabilities.
   *
   * <p>Finishes the activity if Sceneform can not run
   */
  public static boolean checkIsSupportedDeviceOrFinish(final Activity activity) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.N) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Sceneform requires Android N or later");
      Toast.makeText(activity, "Sceneform requires Android N or later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      activity.finish();
      return false;
    }
    String openGlVersionString =
        ((ActivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
            .getDeviceConfigurationInfo()
            .getGlEsVersion();
    if (Double.parseDouble(openGlVersionString) < MIN_OPENGL_VERSION) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Sceneform requires OpenGL ES 3.0 later");
      Toast.makeText(activity, "Sceneform requires OpenGL ES 3.0 or later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
          .show();
      activity.finish();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the method to do this:

```
arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(
            (HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent) -> {

                if (andyRenderable == null) {
                    return;
                }

                // Create the Anchor.
                Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
                AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
                anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());


                MaterialFactory.makeTransparentWithColor(getApplicationContext(), new Color(244, 244, 244))
                        .thenAccept(
                                material -> {

                                    Vector3 vector3 = new Vector3(0.05f, 0.05f,0.05f);
                                    ModelRenderable model = ShapeFactory.makeCube(vector3,
                                            Vector3.zero(), material);
                                    model.setShadowCaster(false);
                                    model.setShadowReceiver(false);

                                    TransformableNode transformableNode = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
                                    transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode);
                                    transformableNode.setRenderable(model);
                                    transformableNode.select();
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable boxo is only valid within the lambda. Change it to:

```
MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(this, new Color(android.graphics.Color.RED))
                .thenAccept(
                        material -> {
                           ModelRenderable boxo = ShapeFactory.makeCube(new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f), new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f), material); 
                           cube.setRenderable(boxo);
                           cube.select();
                           });
```

and it will work